# Android WebView Clear Cookies Programmatically 2017 API 25

Tags: android, cookies, webview

I am doing authentication of my application using facebook login. Everytime I open my app, a webview is lauched and asks for facebook credentials to login in the application.

Only in the first time the user needs to give the facebook credentials, after that the webview stored the cookies/credencials. I tried to delete the credentials programmatically but I didnt had success.

Anyone tried with API24 or API25?

Answer (score 2):

Try this !!

```
mWebView.clearHistory(); 
 mWebView.clearFormData(); 
 mWebView.clearCache(true);
 android.webkit.CookieManager.getInstance().removeAllCookie();
```

UPDATE -

Here is all the functions of webview if someone is getting any other problem regarding webview they can find the solution from here

```
 webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web);
    myLocationManager=(LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webView.getSettings().setGeolocationEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setAppCachePath( getApplicationContext().getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath() );
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess( true );
    webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setCacheMode( WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT ); // load online by default

    url = "https://www.google.co.in/maps/@";

    if ( !isNetworkAvailable() ) { // loading offline
        webView.getSettings().setCacheMode( WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK );
    }

    webView.loadUrl(url.toString());;

    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        public void onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt(String origin, GeolocationPermissions.Callback callback) {
            // callback.invoke(String origin, boolean allow, boolean remember);
            callback.invoke(origin, true, false);
        }
    });


    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

         // For Progress/Loading bar 

        }});
```

Comment: I tried this, but didnt had any success. The web view lauched is the google chrome. DO I need any permissions on the manifest file?